# Powershell Array question

Tags: powershell

I am a newbie to Powershell. What I am trying to do is to go through a text file path.txt (which contains over 500 directories listings) 
Then I need to get what AD security groups are assigned to each of these directories 
and then show the staff comprise of each group.

I have done the following where it will go through the text file and dump me the ACP for each directory that is part of the domain "work"

I have an idea of  what I need to do. 
put the directory text file into an array
from the array select the IdentityReference,FileSys.  For each IdentityReference dump the users that are within-this AD group.

I want to output to a text file/csv
the directory 
the AD group showing the access right . And finally and the users in that group.

repeat the process.
I have done the following which just goes through the first 6 directories and display the security groups only.

cAn someone give me a quick idea ? thanks

```
$path = "c:\path.txt"
$patharray = gc $path
$linebreak = "#########################"
get-acl $patharray[0..5] | select -ExpandProperty access | where {$_.IdentityReference -like "WORK*" } | ft -property IdentityReference,FileSys
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into the active directory module (import-module activedirectory) which is automatically present on any AD server or can be added with AD tools.

Just playing around in a local console window I could do this:

```
$test = get-acl $path | select -expandproperty access
$group = $test[1].identityreference.value.split('\')[1]
get-adgroupmember $group
```

So I assigned the access list to a variable ($test), I split one of the resulting values on the \ character (cos Im lazy/amateur) and then I used the supplied cmdlet to fetch a membership list.

$test[1] was the first group entry ($test[0] being a specific user), and .identityreferencevalue.split('\')[1] just means I grabbed the second element after splitting the string in 2 pieces.

I hope this helps. I am hardly an expert myself. (The Ed Wilson blogs have some great info on querying AD without using the cmdlets. You'll need to do some validation on the group names because you might have 2 identically named groups sitting in different containers)

The other stuff you're piping through (e.g. format-table) isn't necessary until you're actually formatting output. So I wouldn't waste much energy formatting before the data is collected.

Comment: cool I will look into it. right now I am fighting off the flu .